# Is it possible to deploy a C# UWP App directly to a website?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, web

I'm trying to make a UWP App where users have to log in to my website (a hypothetical one as of now). I want the user to be able to run the App while logged into the website without having to download the App to their own computer. I want this website deployment to work in web browsers beyond IE. Is this even possible?

Comment: How would that even work? How would they be able to run an app without downloading it? Why would you want them to run the app if they are **already** logged into your website?

Comment: Now that I think about it it doesn't make much sense. I was thinking of it as just a program made in the.NET framework to be deployed in a website. Would it be better to have a log in system within the app where only users with a subscription can use it?

Comment: Microsoft has an experimental project called Blazor, https://blazor.net/, which is gaining significant interest in the past few months.

Answer (score 2):

You'll be surprised to learn about UNO which is a platform promising UWP everywhere. You can run your UWP app inside a browser (using WebAssembly), Android, iOS, and of course natively as UWP on Windows 10 devices.

https://platform.uno/

Please be aware that as far as i know this is not production ready so you should expect issues, bugs, and weird behavior. Their gitter chat room is somewhat active and the team behind is responsive. But be warned.